# char *newx=p+strlen(str1); how this will execute because strstr will return the pointer to the first match character of the another string

Tags: c++

I can not understand how this code will execute. As far as I know, strstr() will return a pointer to the first letter of the matching string. So, how can we do `char *newx=p+strlen(str1);` when `p` is a pointer and strlen() returns an integer value?

```
p=strstr(str2,str1);
if(p){
   char *newx=p+strlen(str1);
   strcpy(t,newx);
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what adding an integer to a pointer does, it will be good to go through a textbook to understand the fundamentals of the language. Getting an answer to this specific question isn't going to be helpful in the long run. For a list of good books, check out [the definitive C++ book guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You should learn pointer arithmetic. Have a look at https://www.learn-c.org/en/Pointer_Arithmetics

Answer (score 1):

This is simple **pointer arithmetic**.

Adding an integer to a pointer increments the pointer by the specified number of elements.

Say you have a pointer `T *ptr`. When you do something like this:

```
T *ptr2 = ptr + N;
```

The compiler actually does (an optimized) equivalent of this:

```
T *ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr) + (sizeof(T) * N));
```

So, the code in question is using `strstr()` to search the `str2` string for a substring `str1` and get a pointer to that substring. If the substring is found, that pointer is then incremented via `strlen()` to the address of the character *immediately following* the end of the substring, and then `strcpy()` is used to copy the remaining text from that address into the `t` string.

For example:

```
const char *str2 = "Hello StackOverflow";
const char *str1 = "Stack";
const char *p;
char t[10];

p = strstr(str2, str1); // p points to str2[6]...
if (p) { // substring found? 
    const char *newx = p + strlen(str1); // newx points to str2[11]...
    strcpy(t, newx); // copies "Overflow" 
}
```

Comment: what about if(p) bacuase p is a pointer and as much as i know p should be an integer to execute the statement ..in what condition if(p) will not execute

Comment: @AbdaalAhmad a pointer is implicitly convertable to a boolean, where null is evaluated as false and anything else is evaluated as true. All of this stuff is covered by [any decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), I suggest you start reading them

Answer (score 0):

This is a question regarding pointer arithmatic. I suggest you read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm for more info on pointer arithmatic.

For this question, the clarification is, when you add the size of the `str1` to `newx`, it automatically identifies that you're incrementing a char pointer and hence the address needs to be incremented by `sizeof(char) * strlen(str1)`

Hope this clarifies on your issue and highly recommend you to read through pointer arithmatic.